# Optimization problem expressing the area of a page in terms of $x$

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have this problem which I have already answered some steps correctly but I got stucked on one of the steps (shown in the picture by the pop-up of answers).

How do I get the area of the page if the printed area is $xy=58.996$ and the top/bottom margins is $2.4$ cm on each side and the left/right margin is $1.1$ cm on each side?

[image]

Comment: There is no *the* area. You are requested to find the x and y which result in the *smallest* area.

Comment: @MartijnPot Did you look at the picture or read the question? A step asks for it though.

Comment: Solve formula p for y and substitute that y in xy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You have printed text area as
$$(x-2.2)(y-4.8)=58.99636363636\tag{1}$$

And the area of total page is given by
 $$\begin{align}A = xy\end{align}\tag{2}$$

solve $y$ from $(1)$ and plug it in $(2)$

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this right now.

Comment: Solving $y$ from $(1)$ is easy if you don't expand the factors on left hand side... simply divide $x-2.2$ both sides then add $4.8$ both sides to isolate $y$ completely.